# Refer to an external class in a gwt module

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a gwt module in my Appengine project. How can I refer to an external class? In particular I want to create an object X but X is a class defined outside the gwt module. Can I?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a class that you need to use together with your other UI classes, and you do not need it in an external context, then you could create a new module. See 
[this.](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)
If you want to share classes between GWT and the domain classes, for example (like an enum), that is possible too, see [this tutorial](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for response. I don't undestand what I have to do.. I define and use this class X in a package outside the gwt module. Now I need to use it inside the gwt module but during GWT compile I have this error: 
    No source code is available for type com.mypackage.X; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: But why is it outside the module? Do you really need to use it outside the module?
If so, then check out the "source" xml element 
`<source path="path" />`
More info [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml)